# Replacing NAs in two columns

Tags: r, na

I want to do the following NA replacement and I don't know how to tackle it.

I have two columns, looking like the following right now in my data frame:

```
> head(Metaverse[c("Q7","Q8")],10)
# A tibble: 10 × 2
   Q7    Q8   
   <chr> <chr>
 1 NA    1    
 2 1     NA   
 3 NA    1    
 4 1     NA   
 5 NA    NA   
 6 NA    1    
 7 1     NA   
 8 NA    1    
 9 1     NA   
10 1     NA
```

Now, whenever there is NA in both columns (see row 5), I would like to place a 1 in column Q7 instead (whilst leaving the NA in Q8).

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ifelse()` to evaluate the condition when both `Q7` and `Q8` are missing.  If that's true, the result is a 1 otherwise, keep the value in `Q7`.  That's what the code below does.  Note, the data you posted didn't have any such entries, so I changed the `Q7` value for the second observation to `NA` and you can see in the result that it changes to 1.

```r
dat <- read.table(textConnection("Q7    Q8   
NA    1    
1     NA   
NA    NA    
1     NA   
NA    NA   
NA    1    
1     NA   
NA    1    
1     NA   
1     NA"), header=TRUE)   

dat$Q7 <- ifelse(is.na(dat$Q7) & is.na(dat$Q8), 1, dat$Q7)
dat
#>    Q7 Q8
#> 1  NA  1
#> 2   1 NA
#> 3   1 NA
#> 4   1 NA
#> 5   1 NA
#> 6  NA  1
#> 7   1 NA
#> 8  NA  1
#> 9   1 NA
#> 10  1 NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

##### Speed Benchmarks

There was some discussion of speed in the comments.  Here are the benchmarks for the different methods proposed.  Not surprisingly, the `dplyr` pipeline is slower here.  My experience has been that their `dplyr` is slower for small problems and faster for large problems than baseR (though YMMV in any particular situation).  The two baseR approaches are not significantly different from each other, though `ifelse()` has a slight edge.

```r
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark( 
"ifelse_baseR" = {dat$Q7 <- ifelse(is.na(dat$Q7) & is.na(dat$Q8), 1, dat$Q7)},
"rowSums_baseR" = {dat[rowSums(is.na(dat)) == 2, 'Q7'] <- 1}, 
"dplyr1" = {dat <- dat %>% mutate(Q7b = if_else(rowSums(!is.na(cbind(Q7, Q8))) == 0, 1, Q7))}, 
"dplyr2" = {dat <- dat %>% mutate(Q7 = ifelse(rowSums(is.na(.)) == ncol(.), 1, Q7))} 
)
#> Warning in microbenchmark(ifelse_baseR = {: less accurate nanosecond times to
#> avoid potential integer overflows
#> Unit: microseconds
#>           expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#>   ifelse_baseR   5.863   7.4210   9.48658   9.7580  10.9470   14.391   100  a 
#>  rowSums_baseR  12.423  14.5755  18.33192  18.7575  20.2540   33.948   100  a 
#>         dplyr1 762.067 778.2620 898.97338 799.7665 842.2015 7422.886   100   b
#>         dplyr2 664.692 691.5060 783.42718 704.4825 757.5980 2851.222   100   b
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Good gob, benchmarks are always nice. You noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76163462/replacing-nas-in-two-columns/76163828?noredirect=1#comment134322414_76163828) you mentioned that you have done further elaboration, you may want to add that to your answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

dplyr alternative, using `rowSums` and `is.na`:

```r
Metaverse %>%
  mutate(Q7b = if_else(rowSums(!is.na(cbind(Q7, Q8))) == 0, "1", Q7))
# # A tibble: 10 × 3
#    Q7    Q8    Q7b  
#    <chr> <chr> <chr>
#  1 <NA>  1     <NA> 
#  2 1     <NA>  1    
#  3 <NA>  1     <NA> 
#  4 1     <NA>  1    
#  5 <NA>  <NA>  1    
#  6 <NA>  1     <NA> 
#  7 1     <NA>  1    
#  8 <NA>  1     <NA> 
#  9 1     <NA>  1    
# 10 1     <NA>  1
```

(Different name just for side-by-side comparison.)

(We can use `pick` instead of `cbind` if you are using `dplyr_1.1.0` or newer.)

One advantage to using the `cbind`/`pick` and `rowSums` combination is that if you have more than two columns, it is trivial to just add the desired columns to the call, no need to write `is.na` on each of them.

---

Data

```r
Metaverse <- structure(list(Q7 = c(NA, "1", NA, "1", NA, NA, "1", NA, "1", "1"), Q8 = c("1", NA, "1", NA, NA, "1", NA, "1", NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use use `rowSums` with `is.na` to check if equal to number of columns like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
Metaverse %>%
  mutate(Q7 = ifelse(rowSums(is.na(.)) == ncol(.), 1, Q7))
#>    Q7 Q8
#> 1  NA  1
#> 2   1 NA
#> 3  NA  1
#> 4   1 NA
#> 5   1 NA
#> 6  NA  1
#> 7   1 NA
#> 8  NA  1
#> 9   1 NA
#> 10  1 NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's fast, since no `ifelse` is involved.

```
dat[with(dat, is.na(Q7) & is.na(Q8)), 'Q7'] <- 1
```

This generalizes to

```
dat[Reduce(`&`, lapply(dat, is.na)), 'Q7'] <- 1
```

for an arbitrary number of columns (speed should be the same).

Another option is `rowSums`

```
dat[rowSums(is.na(dat)) == 2, 'Q7'] <- 1

dat
#    Q7 Q8
# 1  NA  1
# 2   1 NA
# 3   1 NA
# 4   1 NA
# 5   1 NA
# 6  NA  1
# 7   1 NA
# 8  NA  1
# 9   1 NA
# 10  1 NA
```

### Benchmark `rowSums` vs. `Reduce`

Here is a benchmark on how `rowSums` and `Reduce` solutions above behave with different number of rows *m* and columns *n*. Both solutions were tested on all combinations of *m*=[10, 100, 1,000, 10,000, 100,000] and *n*=[1, 10, 100, 1,000]. Rows were up-sampled and Q8 was simply replicated. Note, that *y*-axis is on log scale.

**Interestingly**, `Reduce` was almost always significantly faster in this study, which might indicate that `Reduce` is preferable to `rowSums` when subsetting for `NA`.

[image]

<sup>AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor 4 GHz,
cache size: 2048 KB, executed on Linux using `R --vanilla`</sup>

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Q7 = c(NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L), 
    Q8 = c(1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Benchmarking the `ifelse()` solution and the `rowSums()` solution shows that the `ifelse()` solution is about twice as fast.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong Where do you show the benchmarking?

Comment: I just put them at the bottom of my post.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong So you used this small data frame for benchmark?

Comment: @DaveArmstrong Indeed interesting! Please try my new solution, and maybe also 100K, 1M nobs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253454/discussion-between-davearmstrong-and-jay-sf).

Comment: Just so people don't have to click into the chat - jay.sf's solution using `with()` is the fastest of all 5 solutions proposed here.  It's comparable to the `ifelse()` solution I proposed in small data and beats both `ifelse()` and jay.sf's `rowSums()` solution with n=10000 (or more).  The `rowSums()` solution is faster than `ifelse()` when n=10000 by a factor of about 2.

Comment: Thanks @DaveArmstrong, I was really surprised that RS performed so poorly and did a comprehensive benchmark.